# Need help to MongoDB aggregate $group state

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I have a collection of 1000 documents like this:

```
{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("628b63d66a5951db6bb79905"), 
    "index" : 0, 
    "name" : "Aurelia Gonzales", 
    "isActive" : false, 
    "registered" : ISODate("2015-02-11T04:22:39.000+0000"), 
    "age" : 41, 
    "gender" : "female", 
    "eyeColor" : "green", 
    "favoriteFruit" : "banana", 
    "company" : {
        "title" : "YURTURE", 
        "email" : "aureliagonzales@yurture.com", 
        "phone" : "+1 (940) 501-3963", 
        "location" : {
            "country" : "USA", 
            "address" : "694 Hewes Street"
        }
    }, 
    "tags" : [
        "enim", 
        "id", 
        "velit", 
        "ad", 
        "consequat"
    ]
}
```

I want to group those by year and gender. Like In 2014 male registration 105 and female registration 131. And finally return documents like this:

```
{
    _id:2014,
    male:105,
    female:131,
    total:236
},
{
    _id:2015,
    male:136,
    female:128,
    total:264
}
```

I have tried till group by `registered` and `gender` like this:

```
db.persons.aggregate([
    { $group: { _id: { year: { $year: "$registered" }, gender: "$gender" }, total: { $sum: NumberInt(1) } } },
    { $sort: { "_id.year": 1,"_id.gender":1 } }
])
```

which is return document like this:

```
{ 
    "_id" : {
        "year" : 2014, 
        "gender" : "female"
    }, 
    "total" : 131
}
{ 
    "_id" : {
        "year" : 2014, 
        "gender" : "male"
    }, 
    "total" : 105
}
```

Please guide to figure out from this whole.

Comment: You can group again on _id.year and take gender `$first`, total `$first`

Comment: @Gibbs, if you have enough, would you please help me how I do this?

Comment: I have taken from your pipeline and altered

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$group": { //Group things
      "_id": "$_id.year",
      "gender": {
        "$addToSet": {
          k: "$_id.gender",
          v: "$total"
        }
      },
      sum: { //Sum it
        $sum: "$total"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$project": {//Reshape it
      g: {
        "$arrayToObject": "$gender"
      },
      _id: 1,
      sum: 1
    }
  },
  {
    "$project": { //Reshape it
      _id: 1,
      "g.female": 1,
      "g.male": 1,
      sum: 1
    }
  }
])
```

[Play](https://mongoplayground.net/p/Eq5cFGzluIR)

Comment: Think you need to update the Mongo Playground link as the query inside the link is different from the posted answer. Anyway, the query from the answer works smoothly. =)

Comment: @YongShun My bad, was playing around

Answer (score 1):

Just add one more group stage to your aggregation pipeline, like this:

```
db.persons.aggregate([
    { $group: { _id: { year: { $year: "$registered" }, gender: "$gender" }, total: { $sum: NumberInt(1) } } },
    { $sort: { "_id.year": 1,"_id.gender":1 } },
{
  $group: {
    _id: "$_id.year",
    male: {
      $sum: {
        $cond: {
          if: {
            $eq: [
              "$_id.gender",
              "male"
            ]
          },
          then: "$total",
          else: 0
        }
      }
    },
    female: {
      $sum: {
        $cond: {
          if: {
            $eq: [
              "$_id.gender",
              "female"
            ]
          },
          then: "$total",
          else: 0
        }
      }
    },
    total: {
      $sum: "$total"
    }
  },
}
]);
```

Here's the working [link](https://mongoplayground.net/p/BNgoXqn4wd0). We are grouping by year in this last step, and calculating the counts for gender conditionally and the total is just the total of the counts irrespective of the gender.

Comment: It works fine, but there is a hard core check 'male' or 'female'. If any change on my document I have to put hands on my aggregation query

Comment: Yeah, first answer is the best

Answer (score 1):

Besides @Gibbs mentioned in the comment which proposes the solution with 2 `$group` stages,

You can achieve the result as below:

1. `$group` - Group by year of `registered`. Add `gender` value into `genders` array.
2. `$sort` - Order by `_id`.
3. `$project` - Decorate output documents.

   3.1. `male` - Get the size of array from `$filter` the value of "male" in "genders" array.

   3.2. `female` - Get the size of array from `$filter` the value of "female" in "genders" array.

   3.3. `total` - Get the size of "genders" array.

Propose this method if you are expected to count and return the "male" and "female" gender fields.

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $group: {
      _id: {
        $year: "$registered"
      },
      genders: {
        $push: "$gender"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $sort: {
      "_id": 1
    }
  },
  {
    $project: {
      _id: 1,
      male: {
        $size: {
          $filter: {
            input: "$genders",
            cond: {
              $eq: [
                "$$this",
                "male"
              ]
            }
          }
        }
      },
      female: {
        $size: {
          $filter: {
            input: "$genders",
            cond: {
              $eq: [
                "$$this",
                "female"
              ]
            }
          }
        }
      },
      total: {
        $size: "$genders"
      }
    }
  }
])
```

[Sample Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/WLVDoY4PBNL)

Comment: It works fine, but there is a hard core check 'male' or 'female'. If any change on my document I have to put hands on my aggregation query